# create a dictionary from json data values

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I'm trying to create a dictionary from 2 json values, so far I can get one and append to an array but instead I would like to combine 2 values as a dictionary and add them to an array.  This is what my function currently looks like:

```
var menuButtonsArray: [String?] = []

func getAppMenuButtons() {
        guard let appJSON = appMenuJSON else {return}
        guard let items = appJSON["items"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
            return
        }

        let filteredItem = items.filter{$0["itemId"] as! String == "Items"}[0]

            if let data = filteredItem["data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                for embeddedDict in data {
                    for (key, value) in embeddedDict {
                        if key == "name" {
                            menuButtonsArray.append(value as! String)
                            print("key: \(value)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

}

This is what the json looks like, it's shortened to fit this post:

```
         "itemId": "Items",
              "data": [
                       {
                       "name": "Item1",
                       "url": "www.item1.com"
                       },
                       {
                       "name": "Item2",
                       "url": "www.item2.com"
                       },
                       {
                     "name": "Item2",
                       "url": "www.item2.com"
                       }
                       ]
```

What I'm trying to do is create an array of dictionaries with the format:

> name:url

so something like :

`["item1":"www.item1.com","item2":"www.item2.com", "item3":"www.item3.com"]`

Comment: That is just a dictionary, not an array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on how you can use `map()` get the array you want:

```
var data = [["name": "Item1","url": "www.item1.com"],
            ["name": "Item2","url": "www.item2.com"],
            ["name": "Item3","url": "www.item3.com"]]

var newData = data.map { (dict: Dictionary) -> Dictionary<String, String> in
    return [dict["name"]!:dict["url"]!] }
```

This code should give you

> [ ["Item1": "www.item1.com"], ["Item2": "www.item2.com"],  ["Item3":
>   "www.item3.com"] ]

as output

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you need a `Dictionary` then declare your result as `Dictionary` instead of `Array`, you can use subscribe to use your `embeddedDict["name"]` as key in your `resultDictionary` and your `embeddedDict["url"]` as your `resultDictionary` value

```
func getAppMenuButtons() {
        guard let appJSON = appMenuJSON else {return}
        guard let items = appJSON["items"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
            return
        }

        let filteredItem = items.filter{$0["itemId"] as! String == "Items"}[0]
        var resultDict : [String:String] = [:]
        if let data = filteredItem["data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
            guard embeddedDict["name"] != nil && embeddedDict["url"] else{
                continue
            }
            for embeddedDict in data {
                resultDict[embeddedDict["name"]] = embeddedDict["url"]
            }
        }
        debugPrint(resultDict) //in resultDict you will have your desired result
     }
```